# JavaScript noob - Passing GET data without "window.location"

Tags: javascript, php

I am sending data to `log.php`

Due to `window.location` page is redirecting when sending data.

can i send data to log.php without redirecting current page?

```
setTimeout(function(){ 

var a = "http://example.com/log.php?c=";

window.location = a+trim;


});
```

Comment: What is trim? This will throw an error trim is not defined.

Comment: Its a variable which i defined previously on code. basically it contains a domain name.

Comment: If you don't want to use ajax then you can put an "image" i the html e.g `<img src="http://example.com/log.php?c=123" />` this would also work when javascript is disabled (though in 2020ish that's not really a concern)

Answer (score 0):

By XMLHttpRequest

```
xhttp.open("GET", "url", true);
xhttp.send();
```